# Proof of a closed-form of $\prod_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{e} \left(1+\frac{1}{3n}\right)^{3n+1/2}$

Tags: calculus, integration, sequences-and-series, analysis, infinite-product

**I'm looking for a proof of the following equality:**

> $$\prod_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{e} \left(1+\frac{1}{3n}\right)^{3n+1/2}=\sqrt{\frac{\Gamma\left(\frac{1}{3}\right)}{2\pi}}\frac{3^{13/24} \exp \left[1+\frac{2\pi^2-3\psi_1 \left(\frac{1}{3}\right)}{12\pi \sqrt{3}} \right]}{A^4}$$
> Where $\psi_1$ is the trigamma function, and $A$ is the Glaisher-Kinkelin constant.

This product is the last entry of this [Wolfram Mathworld page.](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/InfiniteProduct.html)
The product is stated to have been found by Gosper, however, his proof is not listed in the references. I have checked the [OEIS entry of its decimal expansion](http://oeis.org/A100072) also, however, the closed-form is not referenced there either. Assuming, Gosper refers to Bill Gosper, nothing about this product is stated on his [Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bill_Gosper) either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The $\log$ of your product is $$
=\sum_{n\ge 1}  -1+(3n+1)\log(3n+1)-3n\log 3n-\frac12\log(3n+1)-
\frac12\log(3n)
$$
Up to a non-complicated constant coming from the regularization terms this is a mix of $\zeta(-1),\zeta'(-1),\zeta(0),\zeta'(0),\log\Gamma(1/3),L'(-1,\chi_3)$.

- $\chi$ is a an odd Dirichlet character so $L(-1,\chi_3)=0$ and the functional equation relates $L'(-1,\chi_3)$ with $L(2,\chi_3)$, it doesn't have a closed-form because $\chi_3$ is odd, which is where your $\psi_1(1/3)$ term comes from
- $\zeta'(0),\zeta'(-1)$ cause your $A$ term

Comment: Did not downvote. The sum would also just be $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \left(\ln\left(\frac 1{3n}+1\right)\left(3n+\frac12\right)-1\right)$

Comment: ?? The point is that the "closed-form" comes from the values of $\zeta(s),L(s,\chi_3)$ and their derivatives at $0$ and $-1$. In particular the $\psi_1(1/3)$ term **needs the functional equation for $L(s,\chi_3)$**.